# How to change the first node of a svn repository?

Tags: svn

I have a repository which contains a node called *code*, which I want to remove.

[image: Actual root]

I want to have the following as root, without the parent node *code*.

[image: This should be root]

Is there a way to change it?
My thought is too use dump change the dump and reimport. But I hope there is a more easier way with keeping complete history based on the new start node.

If anyone is wondering why there is a node. It is a result of using **svnsync**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suitable way for me. I am using the **dump** and **load** functionality from svn.
*code* is in this case the first node in the folder structure, which should be removed.

After dumping I change the dump file with sed:

```
sed -i -r 's/(Node-[a-z-]+): code\//\1: /'
```

Furthermore the pathes in the **svn:mergeinfo** block needs to be changed.
I have done it via some right good answers from another question of mine ([Search and replace accross multiple lines in large files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21525814/390177)).

The final step is a normal import with **load**.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **svn copy** command to copy those 3 folders from code to root and then **svn remove** to delete the code. Using **svn copy** would prevent your commit history and you don't have to bother with **svn:mergeinfo**. It's never a good idea to manually change **svn:mergeinfo**.

Comment: The use case is to keep the complete history. That is the reason why I am changing **svn:mergeinfo**.

Comment: ups, sorry for my english. I didnt mean the word 'prevent' but 'preserve' :) it will keep the history

Answer (score 2):

Just move them to the root. Substitute the full URLs to your directories below.

```
svn mv /code/branches /branches
svn mv /code/trunk /trunk
svn mv /code/tags /tags
svn rm /code
```