# Search and replace accross multiple lines in large files

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I want to search and replace in large files (about 900 MB). I am searching in the web for hours.

In general there are two tools suitable, sed and perl.
The multiple lines syntax for sed seems to be very komplex, so I have given a try for perl.

My input data looks like the following:

```
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 498
/code/branches/TEST_ENVIRONMENT_OBC/Implementation//SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4670-4976
/code/tags/QR_20131111/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4669
/code/tags/QR_20131211/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5138
/code/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/OBC:4669-4949
/code/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5137-5273
PROPS-END
```

I want to change the **svn:mergeinfo** block and replace part of the paths.
So I have written a small regex for perl.

```
perl -0pe 's/^svn:mergeinfo\nV (\d+)\n(?:\/code(\/(?:branches|tags|trunk)(?:.|\n)+))+\nPROPS-END/svn:mergeinfo\nV \1\n\2\nPROPS-END/m'
```

It works so far, but the path in the output data is only changed for the first occurrence.

```
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 498
/branches/TEST_ENVIRONMENT_OBC/Implementation//SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4670-4976
/code/tags/QR_20131111/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4669
/code/tags/QR_20131211/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5138
/code/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/OBC:4669-4949
/code/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5137-5273
PROPS-END
```

What do I need to change to replace all occurrences of the path?

There is no requirement to use perl to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -r '/svn:mergeinfo/,/PROPS-END/{s#(/code)(/(branches|tags|trunk))(.*)#\2\4#}' inputfile
```

This would perform the substitution between the lines matching the patterns `svn:mergeinfo` and `PROPS-END`.

For your input, it results in:

```
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 498
/branches/TEST_ENVIRONMENT_OBC/Implementation//SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4670-4976
/tags/QR_20131111/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4669
/tags/QR_20131211/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5138
/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/OBC:4669-4949
/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5137-5273
PROPS-END
```

Comment: Wow that was a fast response! But could you please explain a little bit more the sed syntax? I always found multiple lines solution with **N**.

Comment: @CSchulz As mentioned in the edit above, the command performs the substitution between the lines matching the two patterns.  I guess that you can figure the backreference part.

Comment: Yes the backreference part is clear for me, I am just wondering about how the substitution ignores the *V 498*. The part with the comma is the gnu special address format right?

Comment: @CSchulz _V 498_ is _ignored_ because it doesn't match the pattern in the substitution command.

Comment: +1， but the script can be shorter, that `\4` part is useless:  `sed -r '/svn:mergeinfo/,/PROPS-END/{s#(/code)(/(branches|tags|trunk))#\2#}' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe '$/ ="PROPS-END"; s!/code(?=/(?:branches|tags|trunk))!!g' file
```

output

```
K 13
svn:mergeinfo
V 498
/branches/TEST_ENVIRONMENT_OBC/Implementation//SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4670-4976
/tags/QR_20131111/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:4669
/tags/QR_20131211/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5138
/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/OBC:4669-4949
/trunk/Implementation/SpecificComponents/SUV/config/TEST:5137-5273
PROPS-END
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk '/svn:mergeinfo/,/PROPS-END/{sub(/^\/code/,"")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the global flag as well. Multiline only replaces once and then finishes, despite the target being across multiple lines. The global flag makes it continue trying to match until there is no more input text.

Just add a `g` after the `m` at the end of your regex.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. The *g* flag doesn't change anything.  
But it means that I had to run the replacement multiple times till every line is changed?